# TeamCity WebServer with Apache Proxy get "Method GET not implemented (try POST)"

Tags: apache, proxy, teamcity

I am trying setup TeamCity webserver on a server run Apache Proxy.

I added Add this to my Apache conf file

ProxyPass /TeamCity http://localhost/TeamCity
ProxyPassReverse /TeamCity http://localhost/TeamCity

And 
added the Context to my TeamCity conf server.xml file in the Host section

```
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"

        xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">
```

```
 docBase="C:\TeamCity\webapps\ROOT"

 debug="1"

 reloadable="true" > </Context>
```

Anyone know why I still get ""Method GET not implemented (try POST)"?

What is that actually mean?

Comment: To raise the chance people will help you, it's advised to accept some answers of your previous questions first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how this is going to work.. It looks like you're trying to proxy http://your-server/TeamCity to http://localhost/TeamCity, unless your apache is on a different port..?

I've just implemented the a ProxyPass for my TeamCity install. My `<Context>` looks like:

```
<Host ...>
    <Context path="/build" docBase="../webapps/ROOT"></Context>
</Host>
```

..Giving TeamCity the root URL of http://localhost:8111/build - See [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/context.html) for the apache doco on the tag. Without this, TC's Tomcat would redirect you to http://your-server/login.html instead of /build/login.html (results in a 404).

My `httpd.conf` contains (in the mod-proxy section):

```
ProxyPass           /build    http://localhost:8111/build
ProxyPassReverse    /build    http://localhost:8111/build
```

Which will proxy the requests and responses through `/build` to the new TeamCity URL. Works for me!